# is it possible to dynamically assign ID to an element in webpage using JS/ PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, class, dynamic

can i set the id of an element programatically, as in a dynamic setting of id of an element, during runtime of the webpage?

Consider this scenario -

```
<body id="body1">
```

Now, i want to set the id of this element "body" dynamically, using the value of a variable in the php code. Is this possible? something like -

```
<body id=" <?php echo $bodyID; ?> ">
```

I use php and jquery in the page; please let me know whether such dynamic id assignment is possible to the elements in the html.

thanks.

Comment: is $bodyID always set? Would it change on a refresh?

Comment: Yes, you can have PHP output any ID you want. Just remember that any given id **MUST** be unique throughout the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is the background language, it's what produces your HTML output. So basically, what ever you output from PHP eventually becomes your HTML, meaning yes you can use PHP variables as your elemnt-ID or anything else for that matter.

```
<?PHP
$var = "body1";
?>
<body id="<?PHP echo $var; ?>"> Hello my ID is <?PHP echo $var; ?></body>
```

OR You can output all of the HTML using a single echo statement.

```
<?PHP
$var = "body1";
echo "<body id='$var'>Hello my ID is $var</body>";
?>
```

In conclusion, whatever is left after PHP is finished executing is your HTML code that the end users browser interprets... Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks everyone. I had actually tried setting the id of body element using php, as shown in the code in my own example, but somewhere there was problem with the single and double quotes being used in that statement. so that was the issue.

Solved it using php. Thanks everyone.

Comment: No problem, that's an issue with escaping. I had that trouble when I started as well, it's because PHP gets confused and doesn't know where your statement ends. You can read on how to escape properly here, http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    var variable = 'insert_id';
    $('body').attr('id', variable);
});
```

gives (with jquery)

```
<body id="insert_id">
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not? As long as you keep your randomizer ( Math.rand ) big enough there should be little chance for conflicts.

I usually do this, and then at the same time call a JS method and passing the same ID. That would require you storing the ID aside so you can pass it later.

Edit: If you are only setting this on the body then you would not need to access it later.